# Logout User using Loopback in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to logout my user using nodejs in loopback 3

```
var accessToken = 'QqHX4VQoukcElUOmF007jPHcKjaTGknLUZDZ2d6ZHHUIsgncExHqFU8qumD8aCWx';
User.logout(accessToken)
```

Or

```
var accessToken = 'QqHX4VQoukcElUOmF007jPHcKjaTGknLUZDZ2d6ZHHUIsgncExHqFU8qumD8aCWx';
User.logout({accessToken})
```

But each time have `accessToken is required to logout`

Comment: could you provide more details? like the `User.logout()` method

Comment: This is a loopback method http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#user-logout

Comment: Is there a chance that you hit the same issue https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3785